# Got a JPA configuration error in Play Framework 1

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

My application works fine under Play framework 1.2.7.
I decided to try the newest available version from Github: **playframework/play1**, branch: **master**.
My application was compiled fine with "play precompile" but throws an error after run:

> JPA error A JPA error occurred (Found Entity-class
>   (models.vector.VectName) referring to none-existing JPAConfig. Is JPA
>   properly configured?):

What does that mean?
The database configuration in **conf/application.conf** is correct (at least it works well under 1.2.7).

Answer (score 0):

Master is not the newest available version. It's a scary branch of which nobody really knows what's in there and what's not.

The 1.3 branch would be the newest right now. However, in 1.3 they want to add multidb support and therefor JPA / DB configurations won't always be backwards compatible (for now, since they are still working on that).

See the [mailing list thread on the 1.3 release candidate](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/4SiP9SuoKQ0) for more information.